# Invalid texture for sprite

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to load a texture, which is contained in a NSMutableArray, but I'm getting this error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid texture for sprite'

This is how I'm trying to refer to my texture in the mutable array:

```
background = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:[loadedTextures objectAtIndex:0]];
```

This is how I'm generating my textures:

```
  - (void)loadAssets {

        NSArray *imageNames = @[
                                @"bg-001.png",
                                @"bg-002.png"
                                ];

        for (NSString *imageName in imageNames)
        {
            CCTexture * tex = [CCTexture textureWithFile:imageName];
            [loadedTextures addObject:tex];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just an aside: You could use `[CCSprite spriteWithFile:imageNames[0]]` more simply

Comment: But, this would not preload the images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message indicates that the texture is nil. Which is weird because you can't store a `nil` value in an array. That leaves as only possible explanation that `loadedTextures` itself is `nil`.

Check that this (or similar) line initializes the array:

```
loadedTexture = [NSMutableArray array];
```

This has to be before the for loop that fills the `loadedTextures` array.

Comment: Thanks, i tried your approach, and print the array like this  NSLog(@"try preloadedtexture %@", [loadedTextures objectAtIndex:0]); then I get this in the log try preloadedtexture <CCProxy: 0xb978d10> which doesn't look nil for me

Comment: Ah, that's a CCProxy which is used to replace the texture cache. Instead of a texture or sprite frame a CCProxy object is returned which has a weak reference to the texture/sprite frame. If the texture isn't in use elsewhere, the proxy's target (the texture) will be nil, hence CCSprite complains correctly though it should be loading the texture instead. Might be a bug in v3.